# Emitting and receiving socket io within the same file

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to do something where I can set up a route to a link like `/visit` using `app.get('/visit', function(req, res){})` etc. And inside that, I want to emit a message like `socket.emit("event", "a message")` and then inside my `io.on("connection")` function, be able to listen for `event` and return the message. All the examples that I've seen seem to have an example of how to do this when an html page is visited... but how can I do it with just general routes that display something like `res.json()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to emit and listen for events within the same file, you should be using the built in event listeners for node, not the specialized ones for socket.io (https://nodejs.org/api/events.html):

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var eventExample = new EventEmitter;

//You can create event listeners:
eventExample.on('anEvent', function(someData){
    //Do something with someData
});

//To trigger an event listener you must emit:
eventExample.emit('anEvent', someData);
```

Comment: You'd then use the express callbacks to emit to the event listener.